# Python PyAudio installation on windows problems in importing PortAudio V19

Tags: python, windows-7, installation, portaudio, pyaudio

I'm trying to install PyAudio for an application to record audio clips from microphone input.
I installed PyAudio from executable file (Windows 7, python 2.6). However when I try to import this library in my code, I get the following error.

```
Please build and install the PortAudio Python bindings first.
```

I tried the solution provided at [Python PyAudio installation problems (with PortAudio)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12486628/python-pyaudio-installation-problems-with-portaudio?answertab=active#tab-top) but I got the following error message when I installed it using the executable given at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  in <module>
    import pyaudio
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\pyaudio.py", line 99, in <module>
    import _portaudio as pa
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I tried building the [PortAudio v19](http://portaudio.com/) but It also did not work for me.
I'm stuck at this point and I'll appreciate any help in this regard.

Comment: Do you have 64-bit Python with 32-bit module maybe?

Comment: thanks a lot cdarke, it worked. Silly me....

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to first install brew. Check [this](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python) link. Then, write in your command

```
brew install portaudio
```

Once portaudio is installed, run

```
pip install python-pyaudio
```

Comment: Not sure it's a good idea to share your personal info here. You should read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install pyaudio into my project in different ways. But it did not work out and I finally found a way to do it. First I went to this link ([https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio)) and downloaded the .whl file related to my Python version.

How to find correct .whl file?

1. type `python` in cmd.
2. result will be following

[image: result of commanding "python" in cmd]

3. using above result you can find python version and bit value
4. using those data download the required .whl file
5. in above example it was - PyAudio-0.2.11-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl

After downloading required .whl file, copy the path of that file

ex - `C:\Users\Lahiru\Downloads\PyAudio-0.2.11-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl`

Then go to the Python project and open the terminal and run following.

`pip install C:\Users\Lahiru\Downloads\PyAudio-0.2.11-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl`

If the installation is successful, Hurray. Now you can use pyaudio.