# Python PyAudio Portaudio invalid input device

Tags: python, windows, mingw, portaudio, pyaudio

I want to do something like this:
[Get an audio sample as float number from pyaudio-stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629496/get-an-audio-sample-as-float-number-from-pyaudio-stream)

I'm new to Python and installed PyCharm with all necessary packages. PyAudio creates some problems I'm unable to solve.
I have a Win7 64bit and Python 3.4.2 for 32bit. I tried to install Portaudio with MinGW/MSYS as described here:
http://www.portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/compile_windows_mingw.html

I have no experience with MinGW, so maybe I did something wrong there. I also have the impression that the tutorial from portaudio is wrote for someone who already knows what he is doing. Sadly not  my case. Maybe someone can give me one or more hints there.

At last I tried this:
[Python PyAudio installation on windows problems in importing PortAudio V19](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12559778/python-pyaudio-installation-on-windows-problems-in-importing-portaudio-v19)

There is a link to this page:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio

I installed the PyAudio-0.2.8.win32-py34.exe and may PyCharm at least recognize an installed Portaudio.

But now I get this error message if I try to run my code:

```
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pyaudio.py", line 442, in __init__
self._stream = pa.open(**arguments)
OSError: [Errno Invalid input device (no default output device)] -9996
```

I tried a:

```
pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()
print(pa.get_device_count())
```

and get "19".

Hope someone can give me a good advice how to solve this.
Thanks in advance and best regards.
David