# Installing pyaudio on AMD64 from .exe

Tags: python, windows, installation, x86-64, pyaudio

I want to install pyaudio on my Windows 8 x64 machine. 
I have Python 2.7 x64 installed.
Building from source is not an option for me, and anyway I have seen that it failed for others. The Python 2.7 x64 .exe from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ is not working. Is there another way to install? Are there any other places to download from?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very quick Google search yeieded the developers page with downloads. You can try the binary provided there.

http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/

Comment: I missed this before, I see you have 64-bit Python. Why the adversion to compiling from source?

Comment: This is the best link for anything regarding pyaudio on the whole web. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To solve it:

- open "Command Prompt" and type `cls`.
- click on this Link ([https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio))
- install a package based on your version of python and choose either 32 or 64 bit.
- after the download type `cd download` in "Command Prompt"
- press "Enter"
- then type `pip install py`
- finally click on "tab", then "Enter".

Your pyaudio is installed!