# Installing PyAudio on Windows

Tags: python, pip, pyaudio

## Installing PyAudio on Windows 10 error

**I want to install PyAudio**

I have **Windows 10**, **Python 3.7**, **pip 8.1**

I'm installing it in Command Prompt with command `pip install PyAudio`

But there's an error `error: command 'D:\\VisualStudio2017\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2`

```
Command "c:\python37\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-is1aobj6\\pyaudio\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-50bh4kz0\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-is1aobj6\pyaudio\
```

Here's a
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlIuq.png)

*Thanks for reading my question. I hope you can help :D*

Comment: I don't think the *artificial intelligence* tag is relevant

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing pyaudio on AMD64 from .exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573755/installing-pyaudio-on-amd64-from-exe)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bpyaudio%5d%20%5bwindows%5d%20install

Answer (score 4):

Well, I've had just this problem when I wanted to install pylisten (which has PyAudio as a dependency).

There are two problems here - first, your MSVC can't find portaudio.h and after that there will be a problem with the `min` macro when building. But first things first.

## Get portaudio

This is a C dependency for PyAudio, so you need to have include files, in particular `portaudio.h` like you see on the screenshot. It's possible to get binaries for Windows, but if your using Anaconda, the simplest way to do it is to install it using `conda`:

```
(base) C:\> conda search portaudio
Loading channels: done
# Name                       Version           Build  Channel
portaudio                     19.6.0      h0c8e037_3  pkgs/main
portaudio                     19.6.0      hfa6e2cd_3  pkgs/main

(base) C:\> conda install portaudio
(...)
```

Next, we would like to know where the files from portaudio library actually went. There is no `conda package --list` command... (see here: https://github.com/conda/conda/pull/7457), so we need to do some magic found elsewhere on SO:

```
(base) C:\>dir %CONDA_PREFIX%\conda-meta\portaudio*
(...)
26.01.2020  13:17             5 577 portaudio-19.6.0-hfa6e2cd_3.json
```

We need to check this JSON and find the `files` property:

```
  "extracted_package_dir": "C:\\Users\\(...)\\Anaconda3\\pkgs\\portaudio-19.6.0-hfa6e2cd_3",                             
  "features": "",
  "files": [
    "Library/bin/portaudio.dll",
    "Library/include/pa_asio.h",
    "Library/include/pa_jack.h",
    "Library/include/pa_linux_alsa.h",
    "Library/include/pa_mac_core.h",
    "Library/include/pa_win_ds.h",
    "Library/include/pa_win_wasapi.h",
    "Library/include/pa_win_waveformat.h",
    "Library/include/pa_win_wdmks.h",
    "Library/include/pa_win_wmme.h",
    "Library/include/portaudio.h",
    "Library/lib/portaudio.lib",
    "Library/lib/portaudio_static.lib",
    ".nonadmin"
  ],
```

The `extracted_package_dir` (username removed above) actually amounts to:

`%CONDA_PREFIX%\pkgs\portaudio-19.6.0-hfa6e2cd_3`.

So, for this specific build, the necessary include directories (`-I`) are:

`%CONDA_PREFIX%\pkgs\portaudio-19.6.0-hfa6e2cd_3\Library\include`

And link directories (`-L`) are:

`%CONDA_PREFIX%\pkgs\portaudio-19.6.0-hfa6e2cd_3\Library\lib`

This will be useful below.

## Simple way, which doesn't work

Now if your Conda environment has MSVC 14.0 for building native extensions you should be fine with:

```
(base) C:\> pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I%CONDA_PREFIX%\pkgs\portaudio-19.6.0-hfa6e2cd_3\Library\include" --global-option="-L%CONDA_PREFIX%\pkgs\portaudio-19.6.0-hfa6e2cd_3\Library\lib" pyaudio
```

Now, it will find `portaudio.h`!

But alas, at the time of writing, this fails with a compile error. I still put this here, because maybe the incompatibility with MSVC will be fixed.

## The hard, but successful, way

We need to hack the sources of PyAudio. This can be done like so:

```
(base) C:\>pip download pyaudio
```

This will download a file like `PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz` (version number may differ in the future). You need to unpack it, using `tar`. I have it in `C:\Windows\system32` - maybe because of WSL. You can also use 7-zip to unpack it. Anyway:

```
(base) C:\>tar xf PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz
(... unpacked ...)
(base) C:\>cd PyAudio-0.2.11
(base) C:\PyAudio-0.2.11>
```

Now to get the same result as before, you need to pass the special arguments to `setup.py` (in a different way than it's done for `pip`, of course):

```
(base) C:\PyAudio-0.2.11>python setup.py build_ext --include-dirs="%CONDA_PREFIX%\pkgs\portaudio-19.6.0-hfa6e2cd_3\Library\include" --library-dirs="%CONDA_PREFIX%\pkgs\portaudio-19.6.0-hfa6e2cd_3\Library\lib" install
(compile errors: min macro redefinition, __typeof__ undefined)
```

Now, edit the file `src\_portaudiomodule.c`, and delete/comment out these lines (right at the top, line ~39):

```
#define min(a, b)           \
  ({                        \
    __typeof__(a) _a = (a); \
    __typeof__(b) _b = (b); \
    _a < _b ? _a : _b;      \
  })
```

This trivial macro is the culprit. If you want to submit a fix to Mr Pham (http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/), don't delete it, but use something like 
`#ifndef _MSC_VER` ... `#endif`.

Save the file and run this (again):

```
(base) C:\PyAudio-0.2.11>python setup.py build_ext --include-dirs="%CONDA_PREFIX%\pkgs\portaudio-19.6.0-hfa6e2cd_3\Library\include" --library-dirs="%CONDA_PREFIX%\pkgs\portaudio-19.6.0-hfa6e2cd_3\Library\lib" install
```

Everything should be fine now.

## *EDIT*: TL;DR easy way

After checking once again, I saw `pyaudio` in `https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64`. This means, if you're using Anaconda you can just do:

```
conda install pyaudio
```

I'm leaving the rest of this answer for educational purposes.