# PyAudio for 64-bit Linux machine

Tags: python, linux, portaudio, pyaudio

I am having real trouble installing the PyAudio Python module, getting the error:
"Please build and install the PortAudio Python bindings first."

I am running Linux Mint 64-bit with Python 2.7 and have tried installing various versions of PyAudio and Portaudio, compiling from source, using Pip, using software center, un-installing and starting again - but no luck.  I have this running on 32-bit Ubuntu machine with no trouble.

This website takes away my confidence that PyAudio will even work with a 64-bit machine:
http://code.activestate.com/pypm/pyaudio/

I have also tried moving the libraries with no luck, as per:
http://blog.marxy.org/2012/05/build-wspr-on-ubuntu-1204.html

I've invested so much time in getting this to work, and got no further than I was 3 days ago - has anyone overcome this problem in the past, or currently running PyAudio on a 64-bit machine?

Comment: Well, I'm running Linux Mint 64-bit with Python 2.7, and I only see this error when I'm running within a VirtualEnv. This question is Windows-based, but at least shows the code that generates this message. http://stackoverflow.com/q/12486628/1450294 Maybe these are enough clues for somebody to know the answer offhand. If I find the answer myself, when I have time to investigate further (not really worth it right now), I'll post here.