# PyAudio installation problems

Tags: python, pyaudio, portaudio

I am trying to install PyAudio on Python 3.7.

Problem is when I try a simple `import pyaudio` it prints :

`Please build and install the PortAudio Python bindings first.`

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12486628/python-pyaudio-installation-problems-with-portaudio), the problem could be solved by downloading he binaries and installing the wheels.

However `pip install PyAudio-0.2.11-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl` only shows :

`Cannot uninstall 'PyAudio'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.`

Is there any other way to delete completely PyAudio to try the first solution, or do I have to manually build PortAudio ?

I am running Windows 10 64bit.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I managed to solve my problem :

I delete PyAudio and Portaudio files in the libraries folder manually.

Then, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12486628/python-pyaudio-installation-problems-with-portaudio),  I went on [this](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio) downloaded the .whl and installed it with the Windows command : `pip install PyAudio-0.2.11-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl`

It seems to work fine since I have no more error output.